# synchronize two data display components (cxlookUpComboBox and cxDBImage)

Tags: delphi, devexpress

My 'service' and 'logo' fields get their data from a stored procedure.
'Service' data loads into a cxlookUpComboBox while cxDBImage is used
for the displaying of the image (logo).

However they are not synchronised. Selecting a service in cxlookUpComboBox
does not make cxDBImage change so it shows the corresponding logo.
How do I make it happen ?

Also is there a way to avoid cxDBImage displaying the first record while nothing
is selected in the cxlookUpComboBox ?

Comment: Did you check `GraphicClassName` property? did you setup `OnGetGraphicClass` event handler? You need to provide more information here. What image formats you store in the logo field? just `.bmp` images?

Comment: image format is *.png